# Printing HTML field in webkit report

Tags: odoo

How to print **filed.html()** value in report. Earlier i was using rml and failed to succeed printing the rendered html. Then got some idea and tried with the webkit. Still no success

I've described my issue below

**What steps will reproduce the problem?**

1. Have a fields.html() in openerp
2. sample values stored in database is `<div><b>A. Safety Checks<br></b><ul><li>Inspection for visible damage to equipment</li><li>Inspection of mains cord and connecting cables</li></ul><b>B. Cleaning</b><br><ul><li>Electrodes and anything else that comes into contact<br></li></ul><br></div>`
3. Print the values in a webkit report

**What is the expected output?**

Only data with formatting applied

**What do you see instead?**

Pure HTMl code i.e the above code with all  tags

**What version of wkhtmltopdf are you using?**

0.11

I've raised the issue [here](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/issues/detail?id=1233)

Answer (score 0):

it' because fields.html is basically just to storing the data and "Rendering" it on a form view in HTML format, but no in Reporting. Report webkit will not evaluate HTML tags of your data and that's why you are getting HTML code as it is in the print.

Comment: Is there a way to render it in report?